# db.SaveChange(); Exception - value connot be null

Tags: c#, savechanges

In WPF application I want save data to databese.

```
db.Pytanias.Add(pyt); //all parameters in pyt has a value
db.SaveChanges();
```

When is saving to database I get an exception:

```
System.ArgumentNullException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Wartość nie może być zerowa. //value connot be null
Nazwa parametru: source
  Source=System.Core
  ParamName=source
```

It's my second project, in first project I have everything exacly the same and it was working, but I lost it. So i made second the same project i I get the exception.

Comment: Have you put a break point on the db.Pytanias.Add(pyt) and verified that it does have a value?

Comment: Look at the database Table Definition and see if you allow nulls for the column Message: if the checkbox is unchecked and you send a null value it'll throw this kind of error. I think the problem is in your table definition.

Comment: @Robert I put a break point and I checked, and averyone has a value

Comment: Are you doing multiple adds prior to that save changes?

Comment: @user1031034: every property in your object might have a value but may be your object is missing a property and so there might be a field in the database that ends up being null and that could be why the error is occurring.

Comment: @Robert  `var pyt = new Pytania { Pytanie = pytanie, A = Aa, B = Ba, C = Ca, D = Da, Prawidlowa_odp = pr_odp, Stawka = stawka_int };`

Comment: Are you doing any more adds in the database prior to calling this instance of save changes?

Answer (score 0):

If you are 100% sure that all properties which maps to non-nullable columns are populated; then this seems to be related with the navigation properties.

If `pyt` object has some navigation properties, check that they are also populated properly.